# How to insert data into database using formcollection

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, repository-pattern

I am trying insert data into a database table. Unfortunately, the data does not get inserted into the database.

Controller:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                string query = "INSERT INTO Member (@ID, @Name, @City, @Address) " + 
                               "VALUES (ID, Name, City, Address)";

                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);

                //model get,set method does not access
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class UserMasterRepository : IUserMasterRepository
{
    private List<UserMaster> users = new List<UserMaster>();
    private int _nextId = 1;

    public UserMaster Add(UserMaster item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }

        item.ID = _nextId++;
        users.Add(item);

        return item;
    }
}
```

IUserMasterRepository:

```
public interface IUserMasterRepository
{
    IEnumerable<UserMaster> GetAll();
    UserMaster Get(int id);
    UserMaster Add(UserMaster item);
    bool Update(UserMaster item);
    bool Delete(int id);
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @marc_s you need to change your inline query for insertion and before inserting value you need to fetch records from `FormCollection`.

I assume that you have view model something like this.

```
public class VM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public string Adderess{ get; set; }
}
```

Retrieve  input values from  FormCollection Object in action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            //model get,set method does not access
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = collection["ID"];
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = collection["Name"];
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = collection["City"];
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value =collection["Address"];
            ///continue
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: i modified code but still getting same issue can i modify anything in repository class

Comment: you don't need to change anything in pattern just put hard-code value in your parameter and check whether it gets inserted or not?

Comment: so you get better idea about where exactly problem lies

Comment: i debugged code Controller its working fine but its not running repository classes how can i resolve this issue and also record also not inserting in database

Answer (score 0):

I believe for **SQL Server**, your `INSERT` statement is wrong - try this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Member (ID, Name, City, Address) " + 
               "VALUES (@ID, @Name, @City, @Address)";
```

The list of columns after the `INSERT INTO` must list the **column names** as defined in the database table - and those are **without** a leading `@`.

On the other hand, the parameter placeholders in the `VALUES (...)` section are just that - parameters - and **they must have** the leading `@` for their name.

Those parameters must then be defined and a value must be provided for each of them *before* the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` call:

```
//model get,set method does not access
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 42;
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "Miller";
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "London";
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "123 Earl's Court";

sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: i changed code but why it is not inserting record into database.